# How to make custom text and styling

Tags: javascript, css, vue-cli-3

I male website where user can make website profile.
How can user from mywebsite can custom text and styling like make bold, coloring,etc ?

Comment: There are several approaches to accomplishing such. Depending on the technologies that you've used to create your website, there may be different packages that may help you. What you're looking for is Markdown syntax support, and since you've mentioned that you want `coloring` as a feature, you'd either have to extend it or use a different package, of course manually coding it is always an option.

You may want to keep in mind that escaping user input is extremely important in this case. An easy way to get started, for example, is by globally replacing tags with html elements using regex.

Comment: Yes, like markdown but user can styling. If user select word or text, user can click button styling to style, same button to color, button bold or Italia, same button to size font.
I use vue to make website.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to use good wysiwyg editor like https://github.com/scrumpy/tiptap

you can do the basic setup like this

```
<template>
  <editor-content :editor="editor" />
</template>

<script>
// Import the editor
import { Editor, EditorContent } from 'tiptap'

export default {
  components: {
    EditorContent,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      editor: null,
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.editor = new Editor({
      content: '<p>This is just a boring paragraph</p>',
    })
  },
  beforeDestroy() {
    this.editor.destroy()
  },
}
</script>
```

Comment: I use tiptap now, but it's reset my cas class